# Python Pandas if-statement Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I'm having an error in if-statement and I don't know how to fix this error, I'm using Python 3.6 and Pandas for reading, writing and data analysis.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoy10.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])
df2 = pd.read_csv("JonnyTheBoyFull.csv", usecols=['ART_TIPO', 'ART_DESIG', 'PORTA', 'CP4', 'CP3', 'LOCALIDADE'])

    if df1["CP4"] == df2["CP4"] and df1["CP3"] == df2["CP3"]
```

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User01/Desktop/Normmm/Norm.py", line 11, in <module>
    if df1["CP4"] == df2["CP4"] and df1["CP3"] == df2["CP3"]:
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 818, in wrapper
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I need to compare columns of different csv files to get the match between them and finally write in another csv.

Full code for now: https://pastebin.com/DTcTUV6M

Comment: probably `df1` and `df2` have different index. How do you want to compare those columns in this case?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  

The error is saying that the series you are comparing have different indexes. Also put parenthesis to wrap each logical statement.

Comment: I would be easier to answer if you had put in more detail like what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have update have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't super clear, but I assume something like this would work:

```
dfx = df1[(df1['CP3'].isin(df2['CP3'])) & (df1['CP4'].isin(df2['CP4']))]
```

And then run whatever function on `dfx`.

Comment: Get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User01/Desktop/Normmm/Norm.py", line 16, in <module>
    if dfx:
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 953, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Try my update actually, I think it will give you what you want. But per @princelySid, what you do next with the data would better guide the answer to this step.

Comment: File "C:/Users/User01/Desktop/Normmm/Norm.py", line 12, in <module>
    dfx = df1.loc[(df1['CP3'].isin(df2['CP3'])) & (df1['CP4'].isin(df2['CP4']))]
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2555, in isin
    result = algorithms.isin(_values_from_object(self), values)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 421, in isin
    return f(comps, values)

Comment: File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 399, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x, y: htable.ismember_object(x, values)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_func_helper.pxi", line 428, in pandas._libs.hashtable.ismember_object (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:29677)
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got 'long long'

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the series you're comparing are same-sized.

Also, if the compared series are dict data, ensure they all have the same keys (labels).

Example:

```
pd.Series([1,2,3,4]) == pd.Series([4,3,2,1,5])
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

pd.Series({'a':1, 'b':2}) == pd.Series({'a':2, 'c':3})
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```